# android studio app signing taking too long

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Generating a signed android app using Android Studio 3.5.2 is taking more than 20 minutes.
Below is my module `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my app id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.4.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    //google services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    // Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'

    // For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have seen suggestions like removing `com.google.gms.google-services` but in my case, I need it because of Firebase.

i have also enabled `org.gradle.parallel=true` in `gradle.properties` but still the issue persists.
Invalidated cache restarted Android studio still takes too long to wait.
My machine is Windows 10 RAM,12 GB

Comment: what is `proguard-android-optimize.txt`? what is the output?

Comment: I got it from Android studio website. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#remove-unused

Comment: I can not locate its output